# Apply final row value to each group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to target a column value of the final row in my group and apply it to a new column for that group

```
data_frame['New_Col'] = data_frame.groupby(['Group'])\
                        .apply(lambda x: x['Existing_Col'].iloc[-1])
```

But this returns `NaN` for `data_frame['New_Col']`.

Comment: What does the data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dfGroupBy.transform`:

```
data_frame['New_Col'] = data_frame.groupby(['Group'])['Existing_Col']\
                                  .transform('last')
```

The `last` ([by Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925720/apply-final-row-value-to-pandas-group/45925753?noredirect=1#comment78810251_45925753)) specifies that you take only the last value from that group.

Comment: Also can try `.transform('last')` :-)

Comment: @Wen Good idea. In this case, we'd need to access the `Existing_Col` in advance.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ also `nth` can help ~ :-)